# Intersection number of divisors on abelian surfaces and its invariance under translation by 2-Torsion points

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, abelian-varieties, intersection-theory, jacobians, hyperelliptic-curves

I am reading Fulton's but I cannot find a useful result for my problem that seems to be something well known.

Let $\mathcal{J}$ be the Jacobian of a hyperelliptic curve of genus $2$. Consider $D_1,D_2\in \text{Div}(\mathcal{J})$ (two curves inside $\mathcal{J}$) and let $D_2'$ be a translation by a $2$-Torsion point of $\mathcal{J}$.

> **Q:** Is it true that $D_1\cdot D_2=D_1\cdot D_2'$ ?

I cannot see directly that $D_2\sim D_2'$ always. I will appreciate a source in case of being true, or a condition for $D_2$ for this to happen.

Comment: A divisor is always algebraically equivalent to its translates. No ampleness is needed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is *yes* if $D_2$ is an ample curve. More generally, the following result holds:

> Two *ample* line bundles on an abelian variety
>   are algebraically equivalent if and only if they differ by a translation.

This is essentially Corollary 2.5.4 in Birkhenake-Lange book *Complex Abelian Varieties* (it is at p. 40 in the second edition), where it is stated for analytically equivalent line bundles on (non necessarily projective) complex tori.

Comment: Dear Francesco, Thanks for the quick answer, ampleness is very special, in fact I am intersecting the $\Theta$ divisor (which is ample) by the image of the $\Theta$ divisor under an endomorphism of the Jacobian.  The translation I am doing is with the second divisor which I think it is always ample. But I was wondering if it is not ample, the Two torsion preserves symmetry, therefore maybe the intersection numbers will be the same.

Comment: If the self-intersection of the divisor is $>0$, then it is ample (again, this is Corollary 2.5.4 in BL). It seems to me that this is the case, or not?

Comment: At any rate, the general Jacobian has the Néron-Severi group generated by (the class of) the Theta divisor, so *every* effective curve will be ample in that case.

Comment: The hard part of the theorem, is definitely the other direction. A divisor is always algebraically equivalent to one if its translates. No ampleness is needed